# value otp screen cant save in the contoller

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

this my otp field i use flutter_otp_text_field: ^1.1.1
how to save value otptext field to my controller

```
                        OtpTextField(
                          numberOfFields: 6,
                          borderColor: Color.fromRGBO(189, 189, 189, 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),

                          showFieldAsBox: true,
                          borderWidth: 4.0,
                          //runs when a code is typed in
                          onCodeChanged: (String code) {
                            print(code);
                            code = controller.otp;

                            //handle validation or checks here if necessary
                          },
                          //runs when every textfield is filled
                          onSubmit: (String verificationCode) {
                          },
                        ),
```

how to save value oncodeChanged the string to contoller.otp

this my getx controller

```
  int randomNumber = 0;
  int start = 60;
  bool wait = false;
  String  otp = '';
void funVerivikasiEmail() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = prefs.getString('token');
    print(token);
    print(otp);
    try {
      var headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      };
      var url = Uri.parse(Api.base + Api.verifikasi);
      Map body = {
        "email": UserList.email,
        "otp": otp,
      };
      https.Response response =
          await https.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(UserList.email);
        print(otp);
        customSnackbar("Berhasil", 'Verikivikasi Berhasil', 'succes');
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
          Get.offAllNamed('/login');
        });
      } else {
        customAllertDialog(
            'Gagal', jsonDecode(response.body).toString(), 'error');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      customAllertDialog('Gagal', e.toString(), 'error');
    }
  }
```

I create getx controller to access API n post data for my ui

Answer (score 0):

```
OtpTextField(
  numberOfFields: 6,
  borderColor: Color.fromRGBO(189, 189, 189, 1),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
  showFieldAsBox: true,
  borderWidth: 4.0,
  //runs when a code is typed in
  onCodeChanged: (String code) {
    print(code);
    controller.otp = code;
  },
  //runs when every textfield is filled
  onSubmit: (String verificationCode) {
  },
);
```

///

```
void funVerivikasiEmail() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var token = prefs.getString('token');
  print(token);
  print(controller.otp);
  try {
    var headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };
    var url = Uri.parse(Api.base + Api.verifikasi);
    Map body = {
      "email": UserList.email,
      "otp": controller.otp,
    };
    https.Response response =
        await https.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(UserList.email);
      print(controller.otp);
      customSnackbar("Berhasil", 'Verikivikasi Berhasil', 'succes');
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
        Get.offAllNamed('/login');
      });
    } else {
      customAllertDialog(
          'Gagal', jsonDecode(response.body).toString(), 'error');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    customAllertDialog('Gagal', e.toString(), 'error');
  }
}
```